# Oracle - Aggregation of rows and null handling for partitioned set

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, aggregate-functions

Given the following data structure:

```
CREATE TABLE ETL_TEST 
(
    CASE_NO NUMBER(10,0), 
    LINE_NO NUMBER(10,0), 
    COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR2(18), 
    CHANGE_DATE DATE,
    NEW_ENTRY VARCHAR2(255), 
    OLD_ENTRY VARCHAR2(255),

    CONSTRAINT CASE_PK 
        PRIMARY KEY (CASE_NO, LINE_NO, COLUMN_NAME)
);
```

Test data here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2f718c/1

For every set of CASE_NO and LINO_NO one aggregated row with the columns CASE_NO, LINE_NO and REASON_TEXT must be created for which REASON_TEXT contains the data of NEW_ENTRY if COLUMN_NAME = 'REASON_TEXT'.

If COLUMN_NAME = 'REASON_TEXT' is null or there is no COLUMN_NAME = 'REASON_TEXT' then the data of the previous LINO_NO where COLUMN_NAME = 'REASON_TEXT' must be selected (if such an entry exists).

This image should clarify it

[image]

I wonder if this is possible to achieve with pure Oracle SQL. I would know who to solve this in PL/SQL, but with pure SQL? The challenge is that there is no fixed number of COLUMN_NAME = 'REASON_TEXT', because it can be zero or many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions to fill in the missing data -- in this case `last_value()` with the `ignore nulls` option:

```
select case_no, line_no,
       max(case when column_name = 'REASON_TEXT' then new_entry end) as line_reason,
       last_value( max(case when column_name = 'REASON_TEXT' then new_entry end) ignore nulls
                 ) over
                 (partition by case_no order by line_no 
                 ) as imputed_reason_text
from etl_test
group by case_no, line_no
order by 1, 2;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2f718c/10) is a SQL Fiddle.